# How to solve this system of hyperbola equations?

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, circles, conic-sections, multivariate-polynomial

I have a system of 2 equations each describing the branch of a hyperbola. The below equations represent hyperbolae with foci $P_0$ and $C_1$ (or $C_2)$ and transverse axis length $r_1$ (or $r_2)$.  I'm trying to find the unknowns $x$ and $y$:

$$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}-\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}=r_1. \tag{1}$$
$$\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}-\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}=r_2. \tag{2}$$

Where:

$P_0 = (x_0, y_0) = (0.87,-0.5)$
$C_1 = (x_1, y_1, r_1) = (0, 1, 0.13)$
$C_2 = (x_2, y_2, r_2) = (-0.87, -0.5, 0.49)$

These hyperbolae are the result of an algorithm for trilateration I'm trying to compute, known as [Time Difference Of Arrival (TDOA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDOA). I just have no idea where to go from here!

EDIT: For some additional context, here's a graph of the problem:

[image: Graph]

Comment: Your specific $P_0$, $C_1$, $C_2$ appear to be vertices of an equilateral triangle. (That's assuming $0.87$ is supposed to represent the *exact* value $\sqrt{3}/2=0.8660...$.) Are you only interested in this case, or do you want to know what happens for vertices located anywhere? (The formulas are *very* messy in general.) Can you say what the exact counterparts of $0.13$ and $0.49$ are?

Comment: @Blue You're correct - they are vertices of an equilateral triangle and are always fixed at those coordinates. The coordinates of the unknown however will vary. I'm actually not entirely certain what the exact counterparts of those numbers are as I derived them visually (using a graph plotting program, shown in my edit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite the system of equations in their original form,

$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2 =r^2\tag{1}$$
$$(x-x_1)^2+(x-y_1)^2 = (r_1+r)^2\tag{2}$$
$$(x-x_2)^2+(x-y_2)^2 = (r_2+r)^2\tag{3}$$

where $r$ is the radius of the circle with the center $(x,y)$ to be solved.

As seen below, $x$ and $y$ depend on $r$ linearly. It is more convenient to maintain symmetry by solving for $r$ first and then for $(x,y)$.

From (2)-(1) and (3)-(1), we get a pair of linear equations,

$$a_1x+b_1y=c_1+2r_1r\tag{4}$$
$$a_2x+b_2y=c_2+2r_2r\tag{5}$$

where the coefficients are all known and given by,

$$a_1=2(x_0-x_1), \>\>\>\> b_1=2(y_0-y_1),\>\>\>\>\> c_1=r_1^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-x_1^2-y_1^2$$
$$a_2=2(x_0-x_2), \>\>\>\> b_2=2(y_0-y_2),\>\>\>\> c_2=r_2^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-x_2^2-y_2^2$$

Solve the linear equations (4) and (5) for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $r$,

$$x=d_1r+e_1,\>\>\>\>\> y = d_2r+e_2\tag{6}$$

where the known coefficients are,

$$d_1 = \frac{2r_1b_2-2r_2b_1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1},\>\>\>\>\>\>e_1 = \frac{c_1b_2-c_2b_1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1} $$

$$d_2 = \frac{2r_1a_2-2r_2a_1}{a_2b_1-a_1b_2},\>\>\>\>\>\>e_2 = \frac{c_1a_2-c_2a_1}{a_2b_1-a_1b_2} $$

Plug (6) back into (1) to get a quadratic equation in $r$,

$$ar^2+br+c=0\tag{7}$$

with the coefficients given by,

$$a=d_1^2+d_2^2-1,\>\>\> b= 2(e_1-x_0)d_1+2(e_2-y_0)d_2,\>\>\>c=(e_1-x_0)^2+(e_2-y_0)^2$$

The equation (7) for  $r$ can be solved with the standard quadratic formula,

$$r = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Afterwards, plug $r$ into (6) to obtain the solutions for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this - for example there are two defintions of $c_1$ - namely $c_1=r_1^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-x_1^2-y_1^2$ and $c_1 = \frac{2r_1b_2-2r_2b_1}{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}$. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: Yeah, I should have used d and e the second time. Will correct

Comment: Strange... the answers I'm getting are _close_, but not very accurate. The answer should be exactly $x = 0.3, y = 0.1$, but I'm getting $x = 0.262..., y = 0.089...$ and that's with very high precision numbers.

Comment: @jonny - it may be due to the inputs. $(x,y)=(0.3,0.1)$ implies $r_1=0.121$ and $r_2=0.487$.

Comment: ...I'm confused by that. $0.3$ and $0.1$ are exact, and the numbers I'm using have a very high precision. E.g. $$r_1 = 0.123828912277281, r_2 = 0.486486623373764 \\
(x,y,r) = (0.262191959484911,0.089283836443310,0.690245449041083)$$
And even when I substitute in the values you gave for the two radii, x and y are still off by the same amount.

Comment: @jonny - Then, I suspect there may be some glitch in your calculation. I used the implied $r_1=0.1211$ and $r_2=0.4873$ and all the formulas in the answer. I got the expected results.

Comment: Okay Quanto, thank you for clarifying! I'll try to fix the calcuation. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The system of equations corresponds to a special case [CCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_cases_of_Apollonius%27_problem#Type_7:_Two_circles,_one_point) of Apollonius' problem. Namely, $C=(x,y)$ is the center of a circle $\overline{C}$ with radius $r=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$, which is the outer tangent to a circle $\overline{C_1}$ with the center $C_1$ and radius $r_1$, to a circle $\overline{C_2}$ with the center $C_2$ and radius $r_2$, and passing through the point $P_0=(x_0,y_0)$. Let $a=|P_0C_1|=|P_0C_2|=|C_1C_2|$. Let $i=1$ or $i=2$.

If $r_i>a$ then $P_0$ belongs to the inner region of the circle $\overline{C_i}$, so the circle $\overline{C}$ passing through $P_0$
cannot be outer tangent to the circle $\overline{C}$.

If $r_i=a$ then the circle $\overline{C_i}$ passes through the point $P_0$. Let $\ell_i$ be the tangent line to $\overline{C_i}$ at $P_0$. Then the circle $\overline{C}$ is tangent to $\overline{C_i}$ at $P_0$ and lies at the other halfplane with respect to $\ell_i$ than $\overline{C_i}$. Thus $C$ lies on the ray $r_0$, emanating from $P_0$ and extending the segment $C_iP_0$. Let $i’=3-i$. The circle $\overline{C}$ can touch the circle $\overline{C_{i’}}$ ony if $r_{i’}>d$, where $d=a\sin\tfrac{\pi}{6}=\tfrac{a}{2}$ is the distance from $C_{i’}$ to $\ell_i$. On the other hand, it is easy to see that if $r_{i’}>d$ then $\overline{C}$ touches $\overline{C_{i’}}$ iff $(r+r_{i’})^2=(r+d)^2+\left(a\cos\tfrac{\pi}{6}\right)^2$, that is iff $r=(a^2-r_{i’}^2)(2r_{i’}-a)$.

So farther we assume that $r_i<a$. In order to find $(x,y)$ we shall follow the construction proposed in Wikipedia. Make an inversion centered at $P_0$ and the radius $a$ . For $i=1$ or $i=2$ let $\overline{C_i}’$ be the circle in which the inversion transforms the circle $\overline{C_i}$. The inversion transforms $\overline{C}$ into a line $\overline{C}’$ which is a common tangent to $\overline{C_1}’$  and $\overline{C_2}’$. Let $n’$ be a unit (that is of length $1$) normal vector for $\overline{C}’$ and $z’\in \overline{C}’$ be a point such that $z’=P_0+\lambda n’$ for some $\lambda>0$. That is $\lambda$ is the distance from the point $P_0$ to the line $\overline{C}’$. Let $z=P_0+\tfrac {a^2}{\lambda} n’$ be the inversion image of $z’$. Then $P_0$ and $z$ are diametral points of the circle $\overline{C}$, so its center $(x,y)$ is $\tfrac 12(P_0+z)=P_0+\tfrac {a^2}{2\lambda} n’$. So in order to find $(x,y)$ it suffices to find $n’$ and $\lambda$.

Let $z_i=C_i-P_0=(x_i,y_i)-(x_0,y_0)$. Clearly, $|P_0C_i|=a$. Let $s_i=P_0+z_i\tfrac{a+r_i}{a}$ and $t_i=P_0+z_i\tfrac{a-r_i}{a}$ be the intersection points of the circle $\overline{C_i}$ with the line spanned by the points $P_0$ and $C_i$.  Let $s’_i=P_0+z_i\tfrac{a}{a+r_i}$ and $t’_i=P_0+z_i\tfrac{a}{a-r_i}$ be the inversion images of the points $s_i$ and $t_i$, respectively. Then $t’_i$ and $s’_i$ are diametral points of the circle $\overline{C_i}’$. So it has a center $C_i^*=\tfrac 12(s_i’+t_i’)=P_0+z_i\tfrac{a^2}{a^2-r_i^2}$ and a radius $r_i^*=\tfrac 12|s_i’-t_i’|=\tfrac {ar_i^2}{a^2-r_i^2}$. Since the common tangent $\overline{C}’$ is perpendicular to $n’$, contains circles $\overline{C_1}’$, $\overline{C_2}’$, and the point $P_0$ is one of its halfplanes,  considering orthogonal projections of $C_i^*$ onto $n’$, we obtain $\lambda=(C_i^*-P_0, n’)+r_i^*$.  Put $C^*= C_2^*-C_1^*$ and $r^*=r_2^*-r_1^*$. Then $(C^*, n’)+r^*=0$.

Suppose to the contrary that $C^*=0$. Then $r^*=0$, that is $C_2^*=C_1^*$ and $r_2^*=r_1^*$. Then the circles $\overline{C_1}’$ and $\overline{C_2}’$ coincide, and the circles $\overline{C_1}$ and $\overline{C_2}’$ coincide too, which is imposible becuse their centers are distinct. So $C^*\ne 0$.

Let $0\le \varphi<2\pi$ be the angle between the vectors $C^*$ and $n’$. Since $(C^*, n’)=|C^*||n’|\cos\varphi$ and $n’$ is a unit vector, we see that there are at most two possible values for $\varphi$, and so for $n’$.

Assume that there are two solutions $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $\varphi_j$ is the angle between the vectors $C^*$ and $n’_j$ for each $j$ then we have $\varphi_1+\varphi_2=2\pi$. This follows that $n’_1+n’_2=\mu C^*$ for some real $\mu$.

Since we already know $C_i^*$ and $r_i^*$,  $(C^*, n’)+r^*=0$ is a linear equation for conponents $n_x’$ and $n_y’$ of the vector $n’$. Since $n’$ is a unit vector, we also have  $(n_x’)^2+(n_y’)^2=1$. So we can find both possible values of $n’$ solving a quadratic equation. Then we calculate $\lambda=(C_i^*-P_0, n’)+r_i^*$ and $(x,y)=P_0+\tfrac {a^2}{2\lambda} n’$.

Comment: Apologies but all this notation goes way over my head - I'm a beginner when it comes to maths